# export csv data from jupyter notebook to s3

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I know to read in the csv is:

```
    pd.read_csv("s3://data-science/misc/survey.csv")
```

But I am trying to export results into there using:

```
    filex.to_csv("s3://data-science/misc/filex.csv")
```

and this does not work - how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for get the CSV beside the path where you will save it, then try using just the name of the new file and it will be saved in the actual path (from where you excecute the script:

df1.to_csv('df1.csv', sep=', encoding='utf-8')

and I recommend paying attention to the arg's

Comment: I want it saved in the S3 bucket though not where the script is being executed from?